# spring boot - exclude bean from component scan does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

In [this spring boot project](https://github.com/MaxHoefl/springboot-jpademo) an integration test creates a spring application context which should create all necessary beans EXCEPT those carrying an `@ExcludeFromTests` annotation

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes=IntegrationTestApplication.class, 
                webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class IntegrationTest_CartController 
{
     /*....*/
}
```

The test app loads a `@Configuration` class

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo", "com.example.demo.*"}, 
               excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, 
                                                      value = ExcludeFromTests.class))
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.demo.dao")
@EntityScan("com.example.demo.resource")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestDemoAppConfig 
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestDemoAppConfig.class);

    public TestDemoAppConfig()
    {
        // I can see this being printed out
        LOG.info("_________________________________");
        LOG.info("Instantiating TestDemoAppConfig");
        LOG.info("_________________________________");
    }
}
```

That is, it loads beans in the `com.example.demo` packages but should ignore those that are annotated with `@ExcludeFromTests`, such as

```
@Component
@ExcludeFromTests
public class ItemDaoInit 
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ItemDaoInit.class);

    public ItemDaoInit(@Autowired ItemDao dao)
    {
        init(dao);
    }

    private void init(ItemDao dao)
    {
       LOG.info(" ------------ item dao preprocessor called"); // I shouldn't see this when I run a test as this bean shouldnt be created
       /* preprocess entries in dao */
    }
 }
```

When I run the app, I can see that the correct `@Configuration` is loaded but still, the `ItemDaoInit` bean is also created

```
""2018-02-28 11:54:28 [main] INFO  com.example.demo.dao.ItemDaoInit -  ------------ item dao preprocessor called
```

Why is this bean created although it carries an annotation that I clearly exclude from component scanning?

**EDIT**

Btw, the problem persists if I exclude `@EnableAutoConfiguration` from the test configuration class above

**EDIT 2**

This is the `IntegrationTestApplication`. It just scans the `@Configuration` class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses= {TestDemoAppConfig.class})
public class IntegrationTestApplication 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IntegrationTestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: thanks for reply. Please see edit. There is clearly a second component scan initiated by the `@Configuration` class since the `@SpringBootApplication` only scans the `@Configuration` class

Comment: I applied the component scan filter on the `@SpringBootApplication` itself but it still scans `ItemDaoInit` :(

Comment: As stated that doesn't help either, as that still **adds** an `@ComponentScan` it doesn't replace it. `@SpringBootApplication` is `@Configuration`, `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoconfiguration` if you don't want that don't use `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: ok, the test now has `@SpringBootTest(classes=TestDemoAppConfig.class,..)` and `TestDemoAppConfig` should be the only class with `@ComponentScan` but it still loads `ItemDaoInit`

Comment: And why shouldn't it... You have a component-scan which detects. your application and the `@SpringBootApplication` is still an `@ComponentScan`.

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved the same issue in my project. `@ComponentScan` annotation in `IntegrationTestApplication` doesn't have `excludeFilters` declaration which means that in fact you have **2 independent overlapping** `@ComponentScan` declarations and the one from the app loads **all beans** from the package of `TestDemoAppConfig.class` even though the 2nd one from `TestDemoAppConfig` excludes it.

You have to keep the only one `@ComponentScan` annotation (with `excludeFilters` declared) preferably in application class as `@SpringBootApplication` implicitly adds component scanning with the package of the class by default.